# How to implement a core protractor framework for multiple projects

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor, cucumber

there is an idea to implement 'protractor core' which will be used by multiple projects for UI testing. At this moment I have an angular project 'project1' with e2e tests (cucumber-protractor-typescript) which are covering 'project1'. In future I expect 'project 2', 'project 3' ... which is also required UI testing. So I would like to have a separate project let's say 'protractor core' which could be used by any project for develop UI tests. The stucture should be smth like this:

1. project 1 >>> (has dependency to 'protractor core')

   - features
   - step_definitions > (access to api, smth common)
2. project 2 >>> (has dependency to 'protractor core')

   - features
   - step_definitions > (access to api, smth common)
3. project 3 >>> (has dependency to 'protractor core')

   - features
   - step_definitions > (access to api, smth common)

Really appreciate any **examples**, ideas, suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

For a start, understand Protractor is not project related. 
The config file you use to execute your tests will run every file you gave him. In your case, it could be from multiple project folder.

If you already have a config file for each project, create a new one at the top of every project, and give him all project.
One of the possibility is to use the option "suite"

Here a partial example of your config file (eg protractor.conf.js) could look like with this option

```
exports.config = {
  suites: {
    project1: ['Project1/tests/e2e/**/*.js'],
    project2: ['Project2/tests/e2e/**/*.js'],
    project3: ['Project3/tests/e2e/**/*.js']
  },
// more option
```

Your config file needed to be on top the folder. If not, change path according to your structured folder you want. (again protractor is not project related, it's file related)

And you run your test like this:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --suite project1 
# depending on other option you have put in your config file
```

It's another subject. I don't talk about version control, but you will have to think about that for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on something very similar right now. I think my situation is very similar to yours.

What I started noticing is that we have duplicate page objects and helper classes/functions across multiple projects. What we're doing is building an npm package for our protractor framework(page objects, helper classes, etc.) and placing it on our ProGet server. That way every team has access to the same framework and they can just pull it down into their projects just like you would any other npm package. Each project will have it's own config and tests but the framework can be shared across multiple projects and helps prevent duplicate resources across multiple repos.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I want to do. But when i built new npm package i'm getting an issue below: 
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
I believe you have met the same issue, if so could you please suggest how to resolve it ?

Comment: I think you have to use `require` instead of import statements in order for it to work. At least that's how ours is set up. Unless you want to transpile it yourself using Babel or something similar.

Comment: Hey, if you are using typescript in your project may i ask you to share any example how you built npm module and how you included it into you project ? I'm still facing the issue with importing module with my *.ts files. For *.js works fine, but for *.ts it says "npm unexpected token export" when export is a first line in that file ...